# How do i push an array[i] to another array

Tags: javascript

Basically i have to create a quiz with 3category. each with 5questions.
I would have to push the selected category-questions into this new array from the array with all the questions. I am unable to do so.

```
pushSelectedQuestion() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.getNumberOfQuestion; i++) {
        if (usercategory == questionPool[i].category) {
            mcqSelected.push(questionPool[i])
            return mcqSelected;
        }
    }

}
```

usercategory = input from user. 
if user chooses category 1. 
if (1 == questionPool[1].category)   (if it matches the category) then it will be pushed.

This is the part which i cant do

Comment: Where and how is mcqSelected defined?

Comment: It is defined in my class.var mcqSelected = (this.mcqSelected = []);
        var questionpool = (this.questionPool = []);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, from the information you've provided, there's one main issue here - the `return` statement is definitely shortcutting the loop - so even if you have everything else right, you'll only ever get the first matching question. The rest will have been cut out by the return statement, which stops the function and returns the value.

```
pushSelectedQuestion() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.getNumberOfQuestion; i++) {
        if (usercategory == questionPool[i].category) {
            mcqSelected.push(questionPool[i])
           // the below line is causing this loop to end after the first time through the list. 
           // Remove it and then put a console.log(mcqSelected); 
           // here instead to see the value during each iteration of the loop.  
                    return mcqSelected;
                }
            }

}
```

There are a lot of ways to accomplish what you want to do here though. For example, you could just use the javascript `Array.filter` method like so

```
let selectedQuestions = questionPool.filter(question => question.category == userCategory)
```

Comment: pushSelectedQuestion() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.getNumberOfQuestion; i++) {
            if (usercategory == questionPool[i].category) {
                mcqSelected.push(questionPool[i])
                console.log(mcqSelected);
                return mcqSelected;
            }
        }

    }      im not too sure how you did the coding box on the website. i have tried this, not sure whats wrong really

Comment: That's fine we all start somewhere - you only want to use a `return` when that function is ready to stop executing whatever logic it has.  Remove that `return mcqSelected`and see what happens.

Comment: thank you for your encouragement sir! i have removed the return however. it is still not working. i am assuming that nothing is being pushed because it is printing out empty arrays []
[]
[]
[]
[]

Comment: Anytime. Good assumption. Try using `console.log` to log all of the different pieces that you are using...e.g. `console.log(questionPool)` and `console.log(questionPool[i])` and maybe you will find what is missing here.

Comment: I have tried quiz.questionPool. It works at it output all the mcq questions.  as well as questionpool[1] i didnt use i. to test if the array was working and it is. but i cant seem to push it to the other array

Comment: It's hard to debug without seeing the rest of the Class + structures here.

Comment: Couple of issues. One - this.getNumberOfQuestion is a function and it looks like its not being invoked...so that loop isn't actually running at all! Also...a few of your variables are out of scope...e.g. `usercategory` and `mcqselected`, meaning that the function you wrote to get the selected questions doesn't have access to them. They'd need to be state properties instead.

Comment: i have no idea what to do. Do you mind guiding me through?

Comment: Hi. I have somehow managed to get it going. just barely making it. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not understanding your question correctly, but can't you use nested arrays. If the questions are categorized beforehand that is.